# "while read -r LINE; do" is replacing multiple spaces with a single space

Tags: bash, read

I am trying to read in a file using `read` in bash 3.2, but `read` seems to be converting any instance of multiple whitespace into a single space.

For example, the code below has two tabs between "hello" and "there", and three spaces between "today" and "world":

```
while read -r LINE; do
    echo $LINE
done <<< "hello     there
today   world"
```

However, when run, it outputs with only a space in between each set of words:

```
hello there
today world
```

Instead, I'd like it to output the lines with whitespace preserved, e.g.:

```
hello       there
today   world
```

Is there any way to do this? If not with read, then with something else?

Comment: obligatory related link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/117549

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117549

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put quotes around your variable when you print it.  It's being expanded then word split so `echo` is getting `hello` and `there` as separate arguments.

```
echo "$LINE"
```

or better

```
printf '%s\n' "$LINE"
```

will keep your whitespace

so it's not the `read` that's changing your whitespace, it's your not quoting the variable later

Comment: To preserve any leading / trailing whitespace, it's also necessary to unset the field separator variable I think? i.e. `while IFS= read -r LINE`

Comment: @steeldriver You are right, `read` also eats whitespace. Alternatively, you can also do `read -r` and use the `REPLY` variable instead of `LINE`.